# How to add a page on root of site, to quick launch bar

Tags: navigation, quick-launch

I have a user adding a page to an existing site and is unable to add this page to the left-hand navigation menus (quick launch tabs).  Not sure why, but we edit the page and the site settings, but can't find a way to add it to the quick launch list...I know I've seen the option before; we have pages on the quick launch tabs.  We're running MOSS 2007.

Any insight as to what we're missing (I'm sure we're overlooking something) would be appreciated!

Comment: Are you able to see the link in the Site Settings and just not able to add it, or is the user unable to even see the link for the quick launch in the site settings?

Comment: If you can't see the Quick-Launch link Lori mentioned above, you might try altering the URL of the site by replacting "/default.aspx" at the end with "/_layouts/quiklnch.aspx" and see if that can quick-jump you there.

Answer (score 1):

I'd have to agree with Craig, The quick launch link will disappear once you have enabled the "publishing" features.  If you want to get back to the page, then you should use craig's way above by just typing in the URL to the quick launch configuration page.

I just tried it with the publishing feature turned on and it does work.